# How to access the outer caller in nested forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I'm learning [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_building_practice) from MDN.
There is a function 'loop'

```
function loop(){
    ctx.fillStyle='rgb(255,200,124,.35)';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,width,height);

    while(balls.length<15){
        var ball = new Ball();
        balls.push(ball);
    }

    balls.forEach(function(b){
        b.draw();
        b.update();
        b.collisionDetect();
    });

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

`balls` is an array, and in `collisionDetect()` there is another use of `forEach` as below. I want to make `this` in `collisionDetect()` refer to the caller `b` in `loop()`

```
Ball.prototype.collisionDetect = function(){

    balls.forEach(function(bl){

        if(!(this.x===bl.x&&this.y==bl.y
            &&this.velX===bl.velX&&this.velY===bl.velY)){
            var dx = this.x-bl.x;
            var dy = this.y-bl.y;
            var distance = Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);

            if(distance<this.size+bl.size){
                bl.color = this.color = "rbg("
                 + random(0,255)
                 +","
                 +random(0,255)
                 +","
                 +random(0,255)
                 +")";
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I tried passing `b` as parameter of `collisionDetect()`. It does work but not what is expected.

I know two `forEach` can be simply replaced by original `for` loop, but I just wonder if I could make it work with `forEach`.

Thank you all very much.

Comment: In the collisionDetect function 'this' is equal to b. So just capture it in a variable before the forEach and use that variable within the function passed to forEach.

Comment: I question the OO practices used by this article - specifically `collisionDetect`. One instance of `Ball` should not be concerned with an arbitrary variable `balls` from the enclosing scope. Yuck. This should be a "class method" (in javascript's case a property on the constructor function)
`Ball.collisionDetect = function(ball, balls) {}`

Comment: @Damon Maybe the author wants to make code easier to see and understand because that is a tutorial for absolute beginner :)

Comment: @Robba Thanks for your comment. I did try what you said. However, the result is a bit different. In expected result, when balls collid they will change a color and keep moving. In my initial trial, balls don't change colour for collision.your suggestion

Comment: @Robba Thanks for your comment. I did try what you said. However, the result is a bit different. In expected result, when balls collid they will change a color and keep moving. In my initial trial, balls don't change colour for collision. Your suggestion will change ball's colour, but the number of balls decreased as well and finally all balls disppear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind a local variable to `this`.

```
Ball.prototype.collisionDetect = function(){
    var self = this;
    balls.forEach(function(bl){

        if(!(self.x===bl.x&&self.y==bl.y
            &&self.velX===bl.velX&&self.velY===bl.velY)){
            var dx = self.x-bl.x;
            var dy = self.y-bl.y;
            var distance = Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);

            if(distance<self.size+bl.size){
                bl.color = this.color = "rgb(" + random(0,255) +"," +random(0,255) +"," +random(0,255) +")";
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Another way would be to use ES6 arrow functions, because they preserve `this`.

```
Ball.prototype.collisionDetect = function(){

    balls.forEach(b1 => {

        if(!(this.x===bl.x&&this.y==bl.y
            &&this.velX===bl.velX&&this.velY===bl.velY)){
            var dx = this.x-bl.x;
            var dy = this.y-bl.y;
            var distance = Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);

            if(distance<this.size+bl.size){
                bl.color = this.color = "rbg(" + random(0,255) +"," +random(0,255) +"," +random(0,255) +")";
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, two of your suggestion kind of work but bring another problem.

In expected result, when balls collid they will change a color and keep moving. In my initial trial, balls don't change colour for collision. Your suggestion does change ball's colour, but the number of balls decreased as well and finally all balls disppear. Do you know why? If you would like to have a look, there is a finished version in the link at the beginning of the question. Thank you.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem? There's nothing here that will remove balls.

Comment: Thanks Barmar.
This is going with your first suggestion. http://jsbin.com/wikijaxuze/1/edit?js,output
This is for your second suggestion. http://jsbin.com/luvetuzigo/edit?js,output

Comment: It's because you split the `= "rgb("` assignment across multiple lines. Automatic semicolon insertion is putting a semicolon after each line. It would have worked if you put `+` at the end of each line instead of at the beginning of the next line, because a statement can't end with `+`. But a statement *can* begin with `+`, so it treated them as separate statements.

Comment: Thanks for continuous reply Barmar. Well I just did what you said, but number of balls still decreased and all gone finally. Here is the new jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/3b79Lozz/4/

Comment: The balls are all still in the `balls` array, I'm not sure why they're not being displayed. It's like they're being displayed in the same color as the background, so you can't see them. I notice that the background changes color occasionally, but I can't see where that's happening.

Comment: BTW, it's not related to the problem, but you're missing the calls to `random()` when setting the velocities. So everything starts with `velX = 5` and `velY = 5`.

Comment: You're going to feel stupid now :) You have a typo: `rbg` instead of `rgb`

Comment: Now that I noticed the typo, I suspect my earlier point about splitting the line was a red herring.

Comment: That's a great help Barmar, thank you so much to spot that mistake by stupid me, I wish less silly in the new year!

Answer (score 1):

This is the signature of [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
arr.forEach(callback[, thisArg])
```

As you can see, [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) accepts a 2nd param, `thisArgs`, which sets the `this` of the callback when it's executed.

So, pass the current `this` as the 2nd param, and it will be assigned to the callback:

```
Ball.prototype.collisionDetect = function(){

    balls.forEach(function(bl){

        if(!(this.x===bl.x&&this.y==bl.y
            &&this.velX===bl.velX&&this.velY===bl.velY)){
            var dx = this.x-bl.x;
            var dy = this.y-bl.y;
            var distance = Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);

            if(distance<this.size+bl.size){
                bl.color = this.color = "rbg("
                 + random(0,255)
                 +","
                 +random(0,255)
                 +","
                 +random(0,255)
                 +")";
            }
        }
    }, this); // set thisArg to this
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Ori Drori, I appreciate your suggestion, it kind of works but brings another problem.

In expected result, when balls collid they will change a color and keep moving. In my initial trial, balls don't change colour for collision. Your suggestion does change ball's colour, but the number of balls decreased as well and finally all balls disppear. Do you know why? If you would like to have a look, there is a finished version in the link at the beginning of the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the function to whatever context/scope you want. This way it will work:

```
Ball.prototype.collisionDetect = function(){

balls.forEach(function(bl){

    if(!(this.x===bl.x&&this.y==bl.y
        &&this.velX===bl.velX&&this.velY===bl.velY)){
        var dx = this.x-bl.x;
        var dy = this.y-bl.y;
        var distance = Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);

        if(distance<this.size+bl.size){
            bl.color = this.color = "rbg("
             + random(0,255)
             +","
             +random(0,255)
             +","
             +random(0,255)
             +")";
        }
    }
 }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: Thank you @abeyaz, I tried your suggestion, it kind of works but also brings another unexpected result

In expected result, when balls collid they will change a color and keep moving. In my initial trial, balls don't change colour for collision. Your suggestion does change ball's colour, but the number of balls decreased as well and finally all balls disppear. Do you know why? If you would like to have a look, there is a finished version in the link at the beginning of the question. Thank you.